# How to pass optional attribute to the Product via custom add to cart in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I wonder if there's a way to pass some extra information (attribute) by using custom add to cart button.

We've got clear products with their prices. We also sell the same products with print. 
Printed version is more expensive. The product is going out from special generator and there, "add to cart button" will be added to where -if that's possible- I would like to pass attribute to this product (so I could change base price to printed)

Is there any way to pass/add this attribute to the product before it will go to cart?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do that would be use combinations - you can make combination with different prices and then you will be able to send combination_id using your extra button.

Comment: Thanks for replay. The whole thing is product need to be unique, you can do many different prints on it. But when you add new one Prestashop will add quantity not adding new product to the cart